# how to pick value and name for item in listbox in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, listbox, sqldatareader

i want to pick payrollcode when listbox is selected though list should appear as payrollname.Once I have the paycode i can then use it in another query.I have a php background so this is alittle tricky for me.

```
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select tblPayrollCode.payrollcode_name ,tblPayrollCode.payrollcode_code  from tblPayrollCode where tblPayrollCode.systemcode_id=0 and tblPayrollCode.deduction= 'false'", Getconnect)
    Dim dr As SqlDataReader
    Getconnect()
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader
    While dr.Read
        lsttrans.Items.Add(dr.Item("payrollcode_name"), payrollcode_code)
    End While
    dr.Close()
```

Comment: Do you want a list item with a certain string value to be selected in the list box?

Comment: Or do you want to select an item that is at a certain index?

Comment: i want to add both the item and the value i.e payrollname as the item and payroll code as the value but in listbox i should see only payrollname but when i click the payrollname i get the payrollcode value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a class to create objects that keep each display item/data pair. The class needs to specify an overriden ToString method. This method overrides the ToString method of the base class (Object) to ensure that your display item and not the class name is displayed in the list box.

```
Public Class CListItem

Private m_sItemData As String
Private m_sItemDisplay As String

Public Sub New(ByVal sValue As String, ByVal sData As String)
    m_sItemData = sData
    m_sItemDisplay = sValue
End Sub

Public Overrides Function ToString() As String
    Return m_sItemDisplay
End Function

Public Property ItemData() As String
    Get
        Return m_sItemData
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        m_sItemData = Value
    End Set
End Property

Public Property ItemDisplay() As String
    Get
        Return m_sItemDisplay
    End Get
    Set(ByVal Value As String)
        m_sItemDisplay = Value
    End Set
End Property

End Class
```

Execute the loop like this. This adds a CListItem object to the list box's items collection and displays the first parameter that is passed to the constructor.

```
While dr.Read
    lsttrans.Items.Add(New CListItem(dr.Item("payrollcode_name").ToString, dr.Item("payrollcode_code").ToString))
End While
```

You can then retrieve the payrollcode_name and payrollcode_code by adding this code and double clicking on the list box:

```
Private Sub lsttrans_DoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles lsttrans.DoubleClick
    Dim sSelectedDisplay As String = DirectCast(lsttrans.SelectedItem, CListItem).ItemDisplay
    Dim sSelectedData As String = DirectCast(lsttrans.SelectedItem, CListItem).ItemData()

    MessageBox.Show("The selected payrollcode_name is " & sSelectedDisplay & " and the selected payrollcode_code is " & sSelectedData)
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the solution but its now giving me the payrollname eg. house allowance and payroll code is giving me string "payroll code_code" instead of the code itself in the db. what if i used the following   Lsttrans.DisplayMember = "DisplayText" 
        Lsttrans.ValueMember = "Identifier" 
        Lsttrans.DataSource = bsData .Could that be a better fix?

Comment: So the payroll name is displaying OK but the payroll code is giving you a string literal "payroll code_code"? I have amended the loop code above. Give it a go and see whether that works.

Comment: If I try assigning the same to my other listbox i get error object reference not set to an instance of an object Dim transport As String = DirectCast(lsttrans.SelectedItem, CListItem).ItemData() <-works fine  Dim leave As String = DirectCast(lstleave.SelectedItem, CListItem).ItemData()<-gives error.cant seem to correct this. tried to use lstleave.selectedvalue instead which captures nothing

Comment: Is there anything different about the way you are populating lstleave as opposed to lsttrans?

Comment: actually my problem is that if the listbox items havent been selected they give null value.this goes for lsttrans.As such i want it to accept null value as well coz my app accepts the values and uses them in another query upon clicking button.

Comment: see link to vb fiddle.mayb with whole code you can help me determine how to do it.http://dotnetfiddle.net/7g8hQi

Comment: I notice that you are using a data reader to iterate your data. A data reader requires an open database connection. You have closed the connection just prior to executing the "For Each item As CListItem In lsttrans.Items" loop. Try moving the "Getconnect.Close()" command to after the loop and see whether that solves the problem. Do you really want to display the same data in 12 list boxes? If so, I would recommend loading the CListItem objects into a List (Of CListItem) object. I'll post some code to illustrate.

Comment: Here is the form load event procedure using a List (Of CListItem): http://dotnetfiddle.net/yjMwYX

Comment: You're done with the data reader prior to the loop so I don't suspect that closing the connection after the loop will change anything. Was the error occurring in the form load event procedure or elsewhere?

Comment: yes i want the same data so that if one value say transport allowance is picked in first listbox it should not be accessible in the subsequent listboxes

Comment: and it was happening in the form load event.I have however been able to get rid of the error in an odd coding manner.but it works *close enough* :-P.see the code http://dotnetfiddle.net/tFMnQK. problem is havent igured out how to update the listboxes coz it would just keep removing selected items from ubsequent lists

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/52521/discussion-between-gotalovephp-and-guru-josh)

Comment: If you want to chat, try again today and see whether I'm available.In the meantime, I'll continue here.

Comment: So you want one item to be selected from each of 12 list boxes and each is to contain a unique value? When you say that you don't want an item selected in the first list box to be accessible in subsequent list boxes, how does that look? Do you want the item to be removed from subsequent lists or do you want to validate when the use clicks on the button to ensure that each list box has a unique selection?

Comment: I can't see what you have changed in form load to get it to work. I had a closer look at your code. You have a few superfluous calls to Getconnect. I'd create a connection object in the load event and return the connection string rather than a connection object. Have a look at what I have done here and also see the comments in the form load event procedure http://dotnetfiddle.net/yjMwYX

Comment: how do I pass multiple (payrollname and payrollcode) from a multiselect listbox using your solution?

Comment: Do you mean how do you get multiple selected items? If so, iterate the selected items collection like this https://dotnetfiddle.net/FWmfTf

Answer (score 1):

Adding onto @Guru Josh's answer

```
While dr.Read
        lsttrans.Items.Add(New CListItem(dr.Item("payrollcode_name"), dr.Item("payrollcode_code")))
    End While
```

I changed the last bit to the above works fine now.

Comment: Great. As a rule, I'd recommend coding in VB.NET with the "Option Strict On" declaration at the very top of each class file. This declaration disallows implicit conversions and assignments and forces you to make objects more strongly typed. If you include this declaration, the above code won't compile unless you explicitly cast the DataRow.Item property (of type Object) to a string because that's the type that is defined in the parameters of the CListItem constructor.

Comment: That's why I coded it as "lsttrans.Items.Add(New CListItem(dr.Item("payrollcode_name").ToString, dr.Item("payrollcode_code").ToString))".

Answer (score 0):

string col1Value = dr["ColumnOneName"].ToString()

Comment: this really doesnt help me get payrollname to display and payrollcode to be the value